# How to fix "Unfortunately, appname has stopped"

Tags: android

I'm making an app called "pizza hut app". This contains code for a simple login page. When the login button is clicked it must navigate to another page called successful login. But am getting a problem that "Unfortunately, pizza hut app has stopped". Does somebody know how to help?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.pizzahutapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        
    }
    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.getId()== R.id.button1)
        {
            Intent in = new Intent(this,SuccessfulLogin.class);
            this.startActivity(in);
            
        }
    
        
    }

}
```

Successful login (second activity):

```
package com.example.pizzahutapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SuccessfulLogin extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pizzahutapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pizzahutapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SuccessfulLogin"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
       
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Catalog:

```
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pizzahutapp/com.example.pizzahutapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.example.pizzahutapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-16 01:10:13.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The stacktrace in logcat would be immensely helpful, but for starters your `SuccessfulLogin` activity as declared in your manifest needs be written as `android:name=".SuccessfulLogin"` (with the period before the classname, implying that it is part of your com.example.pizzahutapp package).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

And also in your import statements,

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

to

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Lastly, as mentioned in my comment, you should also update your `SuccessfulLogin` activity declaration to read as follows, with a period before the classname:

```
<activity android:name=".SuccessfulLogin"
```

Comment: I have corrected with the help of your suggestion, but its showing the same problem ie; "unfortunately app_name has stopped"

Comment: It is likely crashing due to a different error. Keep reading the logcat stacktrace and google any errors you don't understand. E.g. the first result in google for `cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener` results in a similar casting issue you were having, and one of the answers solves your previous issue. When in doubt, always google the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
how to fix unfortunately appname has stopped
```

You should look at the stacktrace. There is a caused by part which gives you the line number at which the exception occurred. You can go to that line and fix the proble

Also you can use a debugger. Put break points and debug your code.

It should be

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Change

```
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

Should be

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Although this is not wrong

```
  View v = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Suggest to change to

```
 Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
 b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Edit:

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.successfullogin); // remove this statement
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have corrected with the help of your suggestion, but its showing the same problem ie; "unfortunately app_name has stopped"

Comment: @user3199254 is not the same problem. its a crash evertytime a crash happens you should first see the stacktrace. Post it if you need further help by re- running the app

Comment: @user3199254 also remove   `this.setContentView(R.layout.successfullogin);` from `onCreateOptions`. You seriously need to read the docs

Comment: i have corrected as per your suggestion .. but am meeting with a crash again... and am unable to post the catlog completely bcoz it is exceeding 30,000 characters..

Comment: @user3199254 delete the old one and post the new one

Comment: @user3199254 `android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup` this is your problem. but where is the edittext in your code

Comment: @user3199254 your problem seems solved since you accepted the answer

Comment: @user3199254 check this example in the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. Your code does not reflect all the suggestions i mentioned in my post. Also read the link has as example and it will work

Comment: @user3199254 you still have `onClickListener` which is wrong should be `OnClickListener`. I also mentioned the import and  `Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
 b.setOnClickListener(this);` changes

Comment: i have corrected as per the suggestion. And posted the code and also the catlog. Am meeting with the same crash.

Comment: @user3199254 clean and build your project. there is nothing wrong as far as i can see

Comment: @user3199254 remove   `import android.content.DialogInterface;`

Comment: removed import android.content.DialogInterface; meeting with the same crash.. why this happens so?

Comment: @user3199254 did you clean and build as far as i can see there is nothing wrong if your xml has a button with the id `button1`. If this is the code that you have then it looks right to me

Comment: @user3199254 did you clean and build your project. if so there is nothing i can do to help furthere. sorry good luck. also there is a example in the docs did you check that